# JSON query from Postgres for DataTable plugin

Tags: json, postgresql, datatable

I am writing an application which uses datatable plugin. Datatable plugin is configured to use server side processing. Application backend is in c++. To query postgres db ,I am using libPQ.

I am going to write query to get info in JSON.

```
(select row_to_json(temp)  from (SELECT * from eventTable
) as temp)
```

But all i am getting tuples with

```
{"eventName":"Init","id:"78","comment":"someTex"}
{"eventName":"commit","id:"78","comment":"someText"}
```

But DataTable Plugin accept JSON in following format:

```
{
"draw": 1,
"recordsTotal": 57,
"recordsFiltered": 57,
"data": [
    ["Init",
     "78",
     "some"],
    ...
    ]
 }
```

I am noob in sql and bit stuck. I read the refernece page on postgres website but could not help myself. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty old, but the answer might help someone. 
You can build your json response as you like.

Here is an example of what you might do.

```
with 
  base_request as (
    select id, iso2, iso3 from countries 
  )
select row_to_json(t) from ( 
  select 1 as draw, 
  (select count(*) from base_request) as recordsTotal,
  (select count(*) from base_request limit 5) as recordsFiltered,
  ( 
    select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(u)))
    from (
       select * from base_request offset 0 limit 5
    ) u
  ) as data
) t;
```

gives

```
{"draw":1,"recordstotal":239,"recordsfiltered":239,"data":[{"id":3,"iso2":"ar","iso3":"ARG"},{"id":4,"iso2":"au","iso3":"AUS"},{"id":5,"iso2":"at","iso3":"AUT"},{"id":6,"iso2":"bb","iso3":"BRB"},{"id":7,"iso2":"be","iso3":"BEL"}]}
```